When use HTTP v1 FCM API then only receive 403 error in Android device token
I want to send a push notification through the FCM.
I have used HTTP v1 API in PHP and I have also used google/apiclient library to perform this action. The below code is working properly in the iOS device token but when I pass the Android token it shows me the below 403 error.
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/' . $projectID . '/messages:send';
    
    $fields = json_encode(array(
        'message' => array(
            'token' => $token,
            'notification' => array(
                'title' => $message['title'],
                'body' => $message['body']
            )
        )
    ));

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->getAccessToken(),
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    // Initialize curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    // pr($this->getAccessToken());
    // Set curl options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

    // Execute curl
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close curl
    curl_close($ch);

When I run this code I have received below error
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "SenderId mismatch",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
        "errorCode": "SENDER_ID_MISMATCH"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank
